# How can I create a loop in VBA Excel to parse out values between a range indicated in 2 cells into a new cell?

Tags: excel, vba

For example:

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fusjr.png)

I want to take the range between and including cells A1 and B1 and parse it out into cell E1.  Example 1 and 2 show my examples.

If its easier I can split the alpha character and numeric character into different columns as in example 3.

Ive been able to get the numerical values in the cells that are formatted like example 2 but need to attach the letter. The loop will go down the column until there are no more.

[my code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ6Lt.png)

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the code you use. How indicated in 2 cells? I can see in the picture something I cannot understand and I do not know what you need...

Comment: At least, try explaining **in words** what you try accomplishing. I cannot understand from your question. It looks that nobody else understands... Your picture is not so elocvent. It does not have column headers and I do not know how to relevantly refer some used cells. If I understand what you want, I will try helping. Try something like: How to place in a cell value, each cell address of a range. For instance B2:C3, to be returned as B2, C2, B3, C3. Is this what you want? If not, try explaining on a similar way, please.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I added some details, does it help?

Comment: OK. I will paste a piece of code to solve the first two rows. Your picture does not show any column headers. So, the strings to be processed are in the cells in range "A1:B2". The third row already splits B7 in B 7 and B14 in B 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will process the first two rows as (I understood) you need:

```
Sub testSplitRange1()
    Dim strR1 As String, strR2 As String, strLett As String, nrEl As Long, arr, i As Long, lastR As Long
    
    lastR = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 1 To lastR
        strR1 = Range("A" & i).value: strR2 = Range("B" & i).value
         nrEl = Range(strR1 & ":" & strR2).cells.count 'nr of range elements to be returned as comma separated
         strLett = Split(Range(strR1).Address, "$")(1) 'the letter of the addres ("B", in the presented case)
         'obtain (without iteration...) an array containing the necessary elements between the numbers in both cells (in range 7 - 14, for instance):
         arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & Range(strR1).row & ":" & nrEl + Range(strR1).row - 1 & "))")
         'add to the above array elements the letter exttacted above ("B")
         Range("E" & i).value = Replace(strLett & Join(arr, ", ||"), "||", strLett)
    Next i
End Sub
```

For the case of the third row, try the next code, please:

```
Sub testSplitRange2()
    Dim strR1 As String, strR2 As String, strLett As String, nrEl As Long, arr, i As Long
    
        strR1 = Range("A3").value & Range("B3").value: strR2 = Range("C3").value & Range("D3").value
         nrEl = Range(strR1 & ":" & strR2).cells.count 'nr of range elements to be returned as comma separated
         strLett = Range("A3") 'the letter of the addres ("B", in the presented case)
         'obtain an array containing the necessary elements between the numbers in both cells (in range 7 - 14):
         arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & Range("B3").value & ":" & nrEl + Range("B3").value - 1 & "))")
         'add to the above array elements the letter exttacted above ("B")
         Range("E3").value = Replace(strLett & Join(arr, ", ||"), "||", strLett)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great.. you can also add function for the first code giving flexibility not to return to VBA for changing the range.

Comment: @Naresh how do I make it loop through several rows.  For example if I want to do this for 100 rows and make the script stop at a blank row.

Comment: That's where FaneDuru's code works great. It does not loop through each cell but creates an array at once. If you want to find last used row of the B Column then `Cells( Rows.count, "B").End(XlUp).Row`. If you want to find row before next blank cell in B Column from B7, then `Range("B7").End(XlDown).Row`

Comment: @Naresh I am afraid I cannot get you... What "not to return to VBA for changing the range" should mean?

Comment: @Andrewh217 Why are you asking somebody else opinion commenting on my code answer? You said something about trying it and no any feedback. Didn't you find some time for testing it? If tested, didn't it return what you need? About the question regarding the last row where the code should stop, I would do it without any question, if you would have the same data type in your columns. You even did not specify anything in your question about the involved columns... I can (only) deduce that you like the first code and I will adapt it to process all existing range (based on A:A column last cell).

Comment: @Andrewh217 Adapted the (first) code to process all existing range. But if it will contain records like in your third row (from your picture), it will return an error. I can make it processing both cases, but you must **state** it, if this is what you want. Please, test it and send some feedback. I will also like to inform you that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the supplied solution works.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, your code works perfect. With "not to return to VBA for changing the range", I meant if we use function we don't have to edit ranges in the macro as `Range("A" & i).value` for different inputs. User can input it in the function by selecting range or typing.

Comment: @Naresh this is a extremely easy to be implemented, but it depends on the OP needs. I only tried to deduce which is that and tried to answer his question. Looking to his comments, it needs to iterate between all existing range cells and I adapted the code to make it doing that. It also looks that his opinion about sending some feedback is a little peculiar...:)

Comment: @Naresh The question in discussion is obviously unclear. At least, for me... I could only see what he show us and I created a piece of code able to use the data we could see. But, if the data should be "Test17" and "Test14", I mean not able to make a range using them, an elegant solution still exists but using a different way of thinking...

Comment: Yes ..Agreed.. I got confused whether the OP wanted just a series. Atleast, I am happy to learn from you about `arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" &`  .. :).. Thanks ... +1 already

Comment: @naresh both of your codes work perfectly for what I needed. I just need to loop it to do the entire sheet in the case of more than 2 rows of data.  I will be sure to tick for accepted answer.

Comment: @Andrewh217 I am not Naresh... And, as I told you in a previous comment, **I already adapted the first version to do what you say**. Please, refresh the page (this one), use the updated code and send some feedback. Didn't you read my comment starting with "**Adapted the (first) code to process all existing range**"?

Comment: @FaneDuru my sincerest of apologies, I was reading the thread and got the names mixed up. This is perfect and Im not sure I would have figured this out without you. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can enter following function in cell E1

`=RangeCellAddress(A1,B1)`

VBA code for the UDF

```
Function RangeCellAddress(firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range) As String
Dim cl As Range, tempStr As String
tempStr = ""

For Each cl In Range(firstCell.Value & ":" & lastCell.Value)
    tempStr = tempStr & cl.Address & ","
Next

RangeCellAddress = Replace(Left(tempStr, Len(tempStr) - 1), "$", "")
End Function
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment to the FaneDuru's answer. Edited his code to make it a function.

It gives more flexibility as you can mention strR1 as string or a range while entering the formula in the worksheet

For example,
`=testSplitRange1(B7)` and `=testSplitRange1("B7")` will give you the same result.

```
Function testSplitRange1(strR1, Optional strR2) As String
Dim strLett As String, nrEl As Long, arr, i As Long

If IsError(strR2) Then _
    strR2 = Replace(Range(strR1).End(xlDown).Address, "$", "")
    'Selection.End(xlDown) is equivalent to Ctri+Down in a worksheet.
    'If you want last used row (Including blank rows between) in Column of strR1 then
    'replace above == Range(strR1).End(xlDown).Address ==with==
    'Cells( Rows.count, Range(strR1).Column).End(XlUp).address
    
    nrEl = Range(strR1 & ":" & strR2).Cells.Count
        'nr of range elements to be returned as comma separated
    strLett = Split(Range(strR1).Address, "$")(1)
        'the letter of the addres ("B", in the presented case)
    arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(" & """" & strLett & """" & " & ROW(" & _
            Range(strR1).Row & ":" & nrEl + Range(strR1).Row - 1 & "))")
    testSplitRange1 = Join(arr, ",")

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I think..  In excel 2019, 365 you can easily do this with [TextJoin Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) like == `TextJoin(",",False,"B"&Row(A7:A14))`